# CodeWars Deodorant Evaporator

Tags: programming-challenge, f#

How can I make the solution to this https://www.codewars.com/kata/5506b230a11c0aeab3000c1f/train/fsharp more "functional"?

```
module Evaporator
    let evaporator (content: double) (evapPerDay: double) (threshold: double): int =
        let minUsefulAmount = content * (threshold / 100.)
        let evapAsPercentage = evapPerDay / 100.
        let rec solve (content: double) (dayCount: int) =
            let amountLost = content * evapAsPercentage
            let newContent = content - amountLost
            let stillUseful = newContent > minUsefulAmount
            let result = 
                match stillUseful with
                | true -> solve newContent dayCount + 1
                | false -> dayCount
            result
        solve content 1
```

Comment: Hello, to increase odds of receiving more answers you could add the description of the task to the link you already provided and the tag `programming-challenge`.

Answer (score 2):

The first thing that comes into my mind is that if `evapPerDay` is `<= 0` the function will continue infinitely - or more precise: until a stack overflow is encountered. So you have to guard against that:

```
let evaporatorReview (content: float) (evapPerDay: float) (threshold: float): int =
    if evapPerDay <= 0. then 
        failwith "evapPerDay must be greater than 0.0"
    else
        // ... The original algorithm
```

---

The next is that by having the unnecessary local `result` variable `solve()` isn't tail recursive. You can fix that by simply return directly from the `match`-entries:

```
let evaporator (content: float) (evapPerDay: float) (threshold: float): int =
    let minUsefulAmount = content * (threshold / 100.)
    let evapAsPercentage = evapPerDay / 100.

    let rec solve (content: float) (dayCount: int) =
        let amountLost = content * evapAsPercentage
        let newContent = content - amountLost
        let stillUseful = newContent > minUsefulAmount

        match stillUseful with
        | true -> solve newContent (dayCount + 1)
        | false -> dayCount
    solve content 1
```

---

IMO all the temporary variables in `solve()` blur what actually is going on. By skipping them and do the calculations directly in the recursive call to `solve()` the picture is more clear:

```
let evaporator (content: float) (evapPerDay: float) (threshold: float): int =
    if evapPerDay <= 0. then 
        failwith "evapPerDay must be greater than 0.0"
    else
        let limit = content * threshold / 100.
        let rec solve (content: float) (dayCount: int) =
            match content with
            | x when x <= limit -> dayCount
            | _ -> solve (content * (1. - evapPerDay / 100.)) (dayCount + 1)

        solve content 0
```

---

In fact you don't have to calculate on the content, you can do it percentage wise:

```
let evaporatorReview (content: float) (evapPerDay: float) (threshold: float): int =
    if evapPerDay <= 0. then 
        failwith "evapPerDay must be greater than 0.0"
    else
        let limit = threshold / 100.
        let rec solve (remaining: float) (dayCount: int) =
            match remaining with
            | x when x <= limit -> dayCount
            | _ -> solve (remaining * (1. - evapPerDay / 100.)) (dayCount + 1)

        solve 1. 0
```

---

The mathematical "discipline" in question here is exponential growth (`r > 0`) or decay (`r < 0`) and there is a formula for that:

```
Xn = X0 * (1 + r)^n
```

Where `Xn` is `threshold`, `X0` is `100` or `content`, `r` is `evapPerDay / 100.` and `n` is the number of days = the result.

This can be use in sequential calculations ending when the threshold is met:

```
let evaporatorSeq (content: float) (evapPerDay: float) (threshold: float): int =
    if evapPerDay <= 0. then 
        failwith "evapPerDay must be greater than 0.0"
    else
        let limit = threshold / 100.0
        Seq.initInfinite (fun i -> i) 
        |> Seq.takeWhile (fun n -> Math.Pow(1.0 - evapPerDay / 100.0, float n) > limit)
        |> Seq.last
        |> (+) 1
```

---

But even better, it can be solved in respect to `n` as :

```
n = log(Xn/X0) / log(1 + r)
```

which can be used in the function as an O(1) - solution:

```
let evaporator content evapPerDay threshold = 
    match evapPerDay with
    | x when x = 100. -> 1
    | x when x <= 0.0 -> failwith "evapPerDay must be greater than 0.0"
    | _ -> int (Math.Ceiling(Math.Log((threshold / 100.) / 1.) / Math.Log(1. - evapPerDay / 100.)))
```

The division by `1.` is of cause redundant, but it emphasize the relation of the expression to its origin.

`if evapPerDay = 100. then 1` is necessary here because if `evapPerDay = 100` then `Math.Log(1.0 - evapPerDay / 100.)` becomes `Math.Log(0.)` which isn't defined.